# DatagridView Devexpress en .Net Core 2.2, cambia la fecha en el primer registro

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, devexpress

Mi problema es el siguiente:
Tengo un DatagridView de Devextreme (DevExpress) en .Net Core 2.2, funciona bien pero cuando inserto una fecha por ejemplo con hora cero por ejemplo "08/09/2020 00:00" cambia a "08/09/2020 05:00" en el string que llega al método de mi controlador y esto solo pasa cuando el DatagrdiView esta vació, es decir que si tiene al menos un registro ya los próximos llegan bien al controlador, ya actualicé la versión de la librería pero no funciona, he revisado las zonas horarias y no entiendo que esta mal.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ya mencioné si tengo un registro ya añadido no sucede esto, solo pasa con el primer registro que inserto.

Espero puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias.

Comment: No sera que esta enviando como primer dato esa row que se observa en la imagen con los iconos de las lupas? Ademas porque el parametro del action es un string, eso esta mal, deberias usar model binding, definir una clase con propiedades y dejar que asp.net mvc realice el mapping, si envias un json en el request lo mapea automatico, no necesitas un PopulateObject() eso deberias quitarlo

Comment: Gracias Leonardo por tu respuesta, si te das cuenta cod_turno es el primer parámetro que se recibe, por ello puedo concluir que es ese registro y no el de las lupas, ademas si cambio la hora cambia también los otros parámetros pero con una diferencia de 5 horas en fecha desde, ademas hay algo mas curioso aún, si lo agrego así mal como viene y lo borro y vuelvo a agregarlo lo agrega bien pero si actualizo la vista ya se descompone la cosa. La forma de trabajar con ese string es por que así lo recomienda el fabricante de la librería, pero pudiera mejorarlo con lo que propones

Comment: El fabricante no indica que esa es la forma correcta, analiza el ejemplo https://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxGridViewDemos/Editing/EditModes  alli usa una class EditableProduct  como parametro de los controllers

Comment: Me parece muy valioso tu aporte y lo voy a tomar en cuenta.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias Leonardo, pude analizar un poco el caso y conseguí que la respuesta es usar dateSerializationFormat para poder enviar la fecha como corresponde al controlador, ej:

```
columns.AddFor(m => m.Fecha_desde).Format("HH:mm").Width(140).Caption("Hora inicio")
        .EditorOptions(new
        { 
            type = "time",
            dateSerializationFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"
        });
```